# Access userId without having it as a field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing Firestore security rules for my project. I want to allow users to edit information in their own user page, but not in anyone else's. Right now I don't save userId as a field in each user, only as the reference to the user document. I know how to access fields in each user, but not the reference to them. See picture:

[image]

```
match /Users/{document} {
 allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId; //how do I reach the userId without having it as a field
}
```

I do not want to add userId as a field in each user, there must be an easy way of accessing the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) you get the document id from the `match` query.

In your case this would be `document` from `match /Users/{document}`. You could also rename this query to `match /Users/{userId}` to make it work.

Comment: So:
match /Users/{userId} {
 allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId; 

Will work?

Comment: Yep. I don't have a running example currently but I'm pretty sure it worked that way last time.

Answer (score 1):

Check the second example in the documentation on [using authentication information in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions):

> Another common pattern is to make sure users can only read and write their own data:
>
> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
>     // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
>     // available in rules.
>     match /users/{userId} {
>       allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
>       allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

So in your case that'd be `if request.auth.uid == document`.